# How do I pass parameters to the husky or git pre-push hook?

Tags: node.js, push, githooks, autorelease, husky

I have a project in node. In this project I want to standardize commits and versioning. I installed husky, commitzen, commitlint and standard-version.
They work great, my commit is running git-cz and I'm able to standardize my commits. So far so good! But every time I need to run the command "yarn standard-release" and "git push --follow-tags origin branch_whatever", and this is not productive for me.

What I want is, every time I do a "git push" command after a commit (fix, feat or chore), I want to run the standard-release add the options "--follow-tags origin branch_whatever" and then yes run the "git push" command, but if I put this command inside the pre-push hook, it loops on the husky, I've already tried using --no-verify, HUSKY=0 and it doesn't work.

Inside the pre-push hook script I can run the standard-release and "git push --follow-tags origin branch_whatever" without looping, any suggestions to solve this?

Note: Running this on CI/CD is not feasible for me at the moment.

Thanks!

**package.json**

```js
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "release": "standard-version",
    "commit": "git-cz"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@commitlint/cli": "^17.0.3",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^17.0.3",
    "commitizen": "^4.2.5",
    "cz-conventional-changelog": "3.3.0",
    "husky": "^8.0.1",
    "standard-version": "^9.5.0"
  },
  "commitlint": {
    "extends": [
      "@commitlint/config-conventional"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "subject-case": [
        2,
        "never",
        [
          "start-case",
          "pascal-case"
        ]
      ]
    }
  },
  "config": {
    "commitizen": {
      "path": "./node_modules/cz-conventional-changelog"
    }
  }
}
```

=======
**.husky/commit-msg**

#!/usr/bin/env sh
. "$(dirname -- "$0")/_/husky.sh"

yarn commitlint --edit "$@"

=======
**.husky/pre-push**

#!/usr/bin/env sh

#. "$(dirname -- "$0")/_/husky.sh"

yarn release
git push --follow-tags origin "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"

=======
**terminal:**

$ git add .
$ yarn commit

Select example, feat commit

returned: feat: add new router

$ git push

enter hook pre-push

execute script, but looping pre-push script

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.